# advantages VM's have over lightweight containers (docker)

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, docker, lxc

I have the following quote from docker's latest release note -

> Like all major IaaS implementations, Openstack relies heavily on virtual machines. Although there will always be a case for VMs in certain applications, we believe lightweight containers are a great alternative in many scenarios, especially for payloads which are CPU- and memory-intensive and suffer from the performance overhead of VMs.

The above makes it clear that the advantage of docker vs VM's lies in CPU and memory intensive payloads, so my question is what is the advantage VM's have over docker ? Or when should I use VM's ver docker ? As I find that most of my scenarios are well serverd by docker.

Comment: It's worth noting that OpenStack supports LXC as a back-end, so you can run OpenStack with containers instead of VMs if you want to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VM advantage over docker is that VM actually emulate hardware. You will have much finer control over the CPU, network and about everything where on Docker,  you will be limited by host's hardware.

Moreover, with VM, you can run non-linux host like Windows, BSD or Solaris. Docker is limited by its linux kernel dependency.

Comment: as above and no live migration with containers. VMs vs Containers, horses for courses.